# rails slim syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I try to make a simple table in slim

```
table class="table table-striped"
  thead
    tr
      th username
```

it works fine but when I try to add another th or tbody I got an error Malformed indentation, for example this code doesn't work for me

```
table class="table table-striped"
  thead
    tr
      th username
      th provider
```

or

```
table class="table table-striped"
  thead
    tr
      th username
  tbody
    tr
      td test
```

can anybody help me?

Comment: By the way, instead of `table class="table table-striped"` you can type `table.table.table-striped`, i.e., name your classes in a chain separated by the dot. Save your time :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without seeing the raw source I can only guess that [your text editor inserted tabs instead of spaces](https://github.com/slim-template/slim/issues/153#issuecomment-2573547) on the subsequent lines that are at the same level of indentation. Make sure everything is spaces?